# Angular Http failure during parsing for url

Tags: angular, spring, http, spring-boot, angular-httpclient

I got an error while posting form data using http.post method in angular. I am storing form data successfully into database, but http returns parsing error like this:

```
HttpErrorResponse
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttp…, text: "Inserted Successfully"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/api/post"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
```

I could not figure out where is the problem.  API is written in Spring boot
Here is my code

component.ts

```
details: UserDetails = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    adress: '',
    city: '',
    state: ''
  };

    public sendDetails(): void {
          const url  = 'http://localhost:8080/api/post';
          const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(this.details), {headers : headers} ).subscribe(
            data => {
              console.log(data);
            },
            err => {
              console.error(err);
            }
          );
      }
```

Service.java

```
public String postData(Map map) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    try {
      conn = ds.getConnection();
      cs = conn.prepareCall("Begin leo_pack.leo_postUserData1(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); End;");
      cs.setString(1, String.valueOf(map.get("firstName")));
      cs.setString(2, String.valueOf(map.get("lastName")));
      cs.setString(3, String.valueOf(map.get("email")));
      cs.setString(4, String.valueOf(map.get("adress")));
      cs.setString(5, String.valueOf(map.get("city")));
      cs.setString(6, String.valueOf(map.get("state")));

      cs.execute();
      return "Inserted Successfully";

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (cs != null) cs.close();
      if (conn != null) ds.evictConnection(conn);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Controller.java

```
   @PostMapping(value = "/post", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private String test(@RequestBody Map map, BindingResult binding) throws SQLException, ValidationException {

        if(binding.hasErrors()){
            throw new ValidationException("error !!! ");
        }
        return service.postData(map);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.details` don't need to be stringified. Also setting the `Content-Type` header as  `application/json` is redundant.

Give this a try:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, ...) {}

...

public sendDetails(): void {
  const url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/post';
  this.http.post(url, this.details).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
    },
    err => {
      console.error(err);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: @MashrabjonAkbarov, can you please check if this API is working when you send a request to it via Postman?

Comment: yes, it is working fine, only thing that is not working  correctly is http post method in angular